# <ol> list item number not aligned with item content?

Tags: html, css, layout

Weird problem that `<ol>` list item number isn't aligned with its content. See [live page](https://datasn.io/p/446#API-and-Samples) or screenshots: [1](https://postimg.org/image/8ggccy931/), [2](https://postimg.org/image/i0zyzsvu5/)

See the line numbers of the ordered list isn't aligned with its content. They are all down below when the screen is wide and up in the air when the screen is narrow.

Thought it's something wrong with the CSS since both Chrome and Firefox render the list this way, but didn't find any weird styles at all in the stylesheets. Is this normal behavior of HTML5 `<ol>`? How can I make it the item numbers are aligned to the top line of its corresponding content, both wide and narrow screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have applied `display:inline-block` to the `<a>` tags. Just apply `display:block` to the `<a>` tags

***Stack Snippet***

```css
a {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li> <a>http://n3.datasn.io/data/api/v1/n3_lyz/cars_and_powersports_vehicle_and_motorcycle_and_boat_14/atv/list/?app=html-bunker</a>
  </li>
  <li> <a>http://n3.datasn.io/data/api/v1/n3_lyz/cars_and_powersports_vehicle_and_motorcycle_and_boat_14/atv/list/?app=html-bunker</a>
  </li>
  <li> <a>http://n3.datasn.io/data/api/v1/n3_lyz/cars_and_powersports_vehicle_and_motorcycle_and_boat_14/atv/list/?app=html-bunker</a>
  </li>
  <li> <a>http://n3.datasn.io/data/api/v1/n3_lyz/cars_and_powersports_vehicle_and_motorcycle_and_boat_14/atv/list/?app=html-bunker</a>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with the CSS rule for `.links-4 a`. It sets `display: inline-block;`. If you change it to `display: inline`, it'll be fine.